# problems with json and php

Tags: php

I can't understand why is this giving me NULL when i var_dump may i am doing something wrong with referrer part.

```
    $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=cricket";
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    //echo $ref;
    // sendRequest
    // note how referer is set manually
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // now, process the JSON string
    //utf8_encode($body);
    $json = json_decode($body);
    var_dump($json);
```

Comment: What is in `$body` variable ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried pasting the $url straight into a browser and checking you're getting data?

Comment: Same here. Ran it exactly as posted with no problems. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: using the latest php version and it is properly encoded checked it against json_last_error() it gave no error.....now how shall i decode it?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parser in PHP is very strict. Use [`json_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) go get more information why the decoding failed.

If your JSON is encoded as UTF-8 make sure there is no Byte-Order-Mark (BOM). The parser does not work well with BOM as a few people reported at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: i did the following and it returned no error...... now what shall i do why is it not decoding?

Comment: using the latest php version and it is properly encoded checked it against json_last_error() it gave no error.....now how shall i decode it?

Comment: I just tried your script on my PHP environment and it worked perfectly without modifications. Do you have a firewall that blocks outgoing HTTPS connections?